# How to fix search category

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a category selection section that includes 6 options.

This product selection section should be more to the left, but there is no way to move everything together

Maybe there are some suggestions on how to achieve this better with changes

```
<!---Search-->
<section id="search" class="my-5 py-5 ms-2">
  <div class="container mt-5 py-5">
  <p>Search Porducts</p>
  <hr>
  </div>

  <form action="shop.php" method="POST">
    <div class="row mx-auto container">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">


      <p>Category</p>
        <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" value="clothes" type="radio" name="category" id="category_one" <?php if (isset($category) && $category == 'clothes') {echo 'checked';}?>>
           <label class="form-check-label" for="category_one">
          Clothes
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" value="sunglasses" type="radio" name="category" id="category_two" <?php if (isset($category) && $category == 'sunglasses') {echo 'checked';}?>>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="category_two">
          Sunglasses
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" value="shoes" type="radio" name="category" id="category_three" <?php if (isset($category) && $category == 'shoes') {echo 'checked';}?>>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="category_two">
          Shoes
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" value="jackets" type="radio" name="category" id="category_four" <?php if (isset($category) && $category == 'jackets') {echo 'checked';}?>>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="category_two">
          Jackets
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check">
         <input class="form-check-input" value="watches" type="radio" name="category" id="category_four" <?php if (isset($category) && $category == 'watches') {echo 'checked';}?>>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="category_two">
          Watches
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" value="bags" type="radio" name="category" id="category_five" <?php if (isset($category) && $category == 'bags') {echo 'checked';}?>>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="category_five">
          Bags
        </label>
      </div>


      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row mx-auto container mt-5">
      <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">

        <p>Price</p>
        <input type="range" class="form-range w-50" name="price" value="1000" min="1" max="1000" id="customRange2">
        <div class="w-50">
          <span style="float:left;">1</span>
          <span style="float:right;">1000</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group my-3 mx-3">
      <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>

  </form>
</section>
```

For information on what it should look like and how I got it

It should look like this

[image]

and it looks like this to me

[image]

I tried to change the code by applying css with styles but nothing changed as it should

Comment: Try removing mx-auto class.